# Can I use different HP power adapters in one computer?

Tags: adapter, charger

My old HP adapter burned out and it will take 2 weeks for me to get a new one. In the meantime, I borrowed a HP cable from a friend.

Is it possible to use a different HP adapter in the mean time? The specs they have are a bit different.

Old one:

- Input: 100-240V, 1.7A, 50-60Hz
- Output: 18.5V, 3.5A, 65W

New one:

- Input: 100-240V, 1.5A, 50-60Hz
- Output: 19V, 4.74A, 90W

Comment: It will work good as its output is not less than your old one. If the output would be less than your original one then it could be a problem but in this case this will work without problem IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

Since the maximum power output of the new charger is actually greater, you won't have any problems in that department.

The difference between the voltages (18.5V and 19V) is minimal. The majority of recent HP laptops are designed to work at 18.5V, 19V and even 19.5V.

Anyway, your laptop should have a list of compatible chargers the becomes visible if you remove the battery.

For example, the charger compatible with a DV7 2277CL are:

- 18.5V 3.5A
- 18.5V 6.5A
- 19.0V 4.74A
- 19.5V 4.62A

Answer (score 0):

It /should/ be ok, however since the voltages don't match, there's not telling what the charge regulator circuit is expecting, so even a half a volt could be enough to blow/damage something.  I would rec commend looking up compatible chargers for your model, or post your exact model of laptop here so we can help better.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).